# Jquery addClass and removeClass onclick() not working on fontawesome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to change the fontawesome icon on a button when i click on it. i.e
 the button is in a table

```
<tr>
<td> <a href="orders/view/5">#OID005</a></td>
<td> hfg</td>
<td> hhkh</td>
<td> 2015-09-26 16:31:49</td>
<td> 400</td>
<td><button id="#OID005" class="btn btn-info" onclick="work('#OID005','#OID005fa');">
<i id="#OID005fa" class="fa fa-files-o"></i> Take Order</button></td>
<tr>
```

Here is the JS file for that

```
function work(e,f){
    $(f).removeClass('fa-files-o');
    $(f).addClass('fa-spinner fa-pulse');
    $(e).prop('disabled',true);
    $('#damnit').slideToggle();
}
```

Why wont it change the icon?

Comment: remove # in id for elements

Comment: Those are the ids of the elements im passing on to the JS, in my code they are generated automatically,  this is just one example

Comment: they are invalid ids - ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). (from http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `#` in id

```
<button id="OID005" class="btn btn-info" onclick="work('OID005','OID005fa');">
     <i id="OID005fa" class="fa fa-files-o"></i> Take Order
</button>
```

and change you `work()` like this,

```
function work(e, f) {
            $("#"+f).removeClass('fa-files-o');
            $("#"+f).addClass('fa-spinner fa-pulse');
            $("#"+e).prop('disabled', true);
            $('#damnit').slideToggle();
        }
```